# DateTimeFormatter cannot parse string produced by itself

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

I have issue with parsing following date format:

```
2017-03-27T08:27:43.326TGMT-05:00
```

I have code where `DateTimeFormatter` produces string out of `ZonedDateTime` and as a next step I am trying to parse this string again and create `ZonedDateTime` instance, however it doesn't work as I expected:

```
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'T'ZZZZ";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
String dateStr = ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter);

System.out.println(dateStr);

ZonedDateTime dateParsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
System.out.println(dateParsed);
```

The code above produces:

```
2017-03-27T08:27:43.326TGMT-05:00
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-03-27T08:27:43.326TGMT-05:00' could not be parsed: String index out of range: 33

    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
```

Looking for any insight on how to come up with working pattern that is capable to create `ZonedDateTime` instance out of `2017-03-27T08:27:43.326TGMT-05:00`

Comment: change your pattern to: `String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'T'ZZZZZ";` (one Z more) and it works

Comment: Also seems to work with just three Zs.

Comment: @BrianClapper but three Zs cause the output to be slightly different than what OP had `..512T-0500` instead of `..512TGMT-05:00`

Comment: Agreed. I was simply adding another data point. ZZZ and ZZZZZ work, but ZZZZ does not. Seems like a bug in the JDK, to me. Regardless, the OP now has some options available.

Comment: See the documentation (scroll down) to see the difference between four and five Z, and also note pattern letter x - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake to understand what's wrong I had a look at source code of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:3563` where the exception was raised.

I saw there is a piece of code that parse even the seconds parts after `GMT-05:00`.

So it will work only if you add the seconds part...

```
ZonedDateTime dateParsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr+":00", formatter);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like this, but still this is odd situation and I want to try to figure out better solution

Answer (score 0):

To understand what the `ZZZZ` pattern does, take a look at the [JDK docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-), where you can see its meaning:

```
Pattern  Count  Equivalent builder methods
-------  -----  --------------------------
ZZZZ     4      appendLocalizedOffset(TextStyle.FULL);
```

So, `ZZZZ` is equivalent to `appendLocalizedOffset(TextStyle.FULL)`. If you look at [appendLocalizedOffset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendLocalizedOffset-java.time.format.TextStyle-) method:

> Appends the localized zone offset, such as **'GMT+01:00'**, to the formatter.
>   This appends a localized zone offset to the builder, the format of the localized offset is controlled by the specified style to this method:
>
> - **full** - formats with localized offset text, such as '**GMT**, 2-digit hour and minute field, **optional second field if non-zero**, and colon.

And note that it has different behaviours when parsing and formatting:

> During **formatting**, the offset is obtained using a mechanism equivalent to querying the temporal with TemporalQueries.offset(). If the offset cannot be obtained then an exception is thrown unless the section of the formatter is optional.
>
> During **parsing**, the offset is parsed using the format defined above. If the offset cannot be parsed then an exception is thrown unless the section of the formatter is optional.

So, it seems that `ZZZZ` pattern adds the `GMT-05:00` when formatting (without the seconds when it's zero), but when parsing, it tries to parse the seconds (even when they're not present).
That's why, when parsing, you need to add `:00` in the end (as @freedev did [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43048868/7605325)).

As `ZZZZ` seems to be the only pattern that adds `GMT` before the offset (all the others just add the offset without `GMT`), I think the only solution is to add it by hand. You can do it using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // append the yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS pattern
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    // append "T" and "GMT"
    .appendLiteral("TGMT")
    // append the offset (-05:00)
    .appendOffsetId()
    .toFormatter();
```

With this formatter, your code will work as expected:

```
String dateStr = ZonedDateTime.now().format(formatter);
System.out.println(dateStr);

ZonedDateTime dateParsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, formatter);
System.out.println(dateParsed);
```

Output:

> 2017-05-25T08:42:17.799TGMT-05:00
>
> 2017-05-25T08:42:17.799-05:00

---

Testing with your input:

```
String input = "2017-03-27T08:27:43.326TGMT-05:00";
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(input, formatter));
```

Output:

> 2017-03-27T08:27:43.326TGMT-05:00
>
> 2017-03-27T08:27:43.326-05:00

---

**PS:** In cases like this I prefer to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, but you can do the same using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` directly:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'TGMT'xxx");
```

This works exactly the same way.